# How to simulate Ruby's until loop in Elixir?

Tags: recursion, elixir

I'm converting a Ruby project to Elixir. How does Ruby's [until](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-until+Loop) loop translate to Elixir?

```ruby
until scanner.eos? do
  tokens << scan(line + 1)
end
```

Here's the full Ruby method:

```ruby
def tokenize
  @tokens = []
  @lines.each_with_index do |text, line|
    @scanner = StringScanner.new(text)
    until @scanner.eos? do
      @tokens << scan(line + 1)
    end
  end
  @tokens
end
```

`@lines` is just a text file split by new lines.  `@lines = text.split("\n")`

In Elixir, I've already converted the [string scanner](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/strscan/rdoc/StringScanner.html) which looks like this: `StringScanner.eos?(scanner)`:

```elixir
@spec eos?(pid) :: boolean
def eos?(pid) when is_pid(pid) do
```

Also, in Elixir, tokens are tuples:  `@type token :: {:atom, any, {integer, integer}}`. Where the `{integer, integer}` tuple is the `line` and `position` of the token.

This is the Elixir psuedo-code which doesn't quite work.

```elixir
@spec scan(String.t, integer) :: token
def scan(text, line) when is_binary(text) and is_integer(line) do
  string_scanner = StringScanner.new(text)
  until StringScanner.eos?(string_scanner) do
    result = Enum.find_value(@scanner_tokenizers, fn {scanner, tokenizer} ->
      match = scanner.(string_scanner)
      if match do
        tokenizer.(string_scanner, match, line)
      end
    end)
    IO.inspect result
  end
  StringScanner.stop(string_scanner)
  result
end
```

Someone on the [slack channel](https://elixir-slackin.herokuapp.com) suggested using **recursion**, however they didn't elaborate with an example. I've seen recursion examples for summing / reducing which use accumulators etc.  However, I don't see how that applies when evaluating a boolean.

Can anyone provide a working example which uses `StringScanner.eos?(scanner)`?  Thanks.

Comment: I'd say you're asking the wrong question. Please explain what is your end goal and it might be easier to suggest a good solution. The question as is right now, for me, makes really very little sense.

Comment: I have a tokenizer which splits a text file into individual lines, it then loops through each line, and gives a line to the StringScanner, which loops through the line matching patterns.  Just like the Ruby version, the string scanner move a pointer each time a scan is matched.  eos? returns true if the end of the string has been reached.  In Ruby I used an `until` loop.

Answer (score 2):

It may be something like

```
def tokens(scanner) do
  tokens(scanner, [])
end

defp tokens(scanner, acc) do
  if StringScanner.eos?(scanner) do
    acc
  else
    tokens(scanner, add_to_acc(scan_stuff(), acc))
  end
end
```

At least this can be the general idea. As you'll see I kept a couple of functions very generic (`scan_stuff/0` and `add_to_acc/2`) as I don't know how you mean to implement those; the first one is meant to do what `scan(line + 1)` does in the Ruby code, while the second one is meant to do what `<<` does in the Ruby code (e.g., it could add the scanned stuff to the list of tokens or something similar).

Comment: Okay.  How would `add_to_acc` work? In my case tokens is a list of tuples.  For example, a token could look like this: `{:new_line, "\n", {1, 1}}`.  The typespec:  `@type token :: {:atom, any, {integer, integer}}`.  I guess I don't understand how it's initialized with an empty list `[]` and then ends up with things in the list when no variable is declared.

Comment: Never mind. I found your excellent answer on [How does recursion work in Elixir](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33926891/691816). I think I understand that better now.  I just need to figure out how to work this into my code...

Comment: @EdwardJ.Stembler ping me on #elixir-lang IRC (whatyouide) if you need further help :)